# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycountry'

Tags: python

I received this error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycountry'

despite installing pycountry using pip install pycountry

How do I make the program import pycountry?

Here is the part of the code:

```
import pycountry
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
# ----------- Step 1 ------------
URL_DATASET = r'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/master/data/countries-aggregated.csv'
df1 = pd.read_csv(URL_DATASET)
```

Comment: How are you running the code?  Do you type `python myscript.py` on the command line, or do you use an IDE?

Comment: You probably have more than a single Python installed. On Mac or Linux check which version you are using with *which python3* and use *pip3* and *python3* instead of `python2 if you're sure it's Python 3. If using PyCharm configure your project properties to use the right version and location of Python.